# Erlang. Start remote shell error

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I tried to start remote shell and get a following error:

```
*** ERROR: Shell process terminated! (^G to start new job) ***
```

Details: 
1. Start erlang on a computer a2-x201:

```
erl -sname a@a2-x201

Erlang R14B (erts-5.8.1) [source] [smp:4:4] [rq:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe]     [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.8.1  (abort with ^G)
(a@a2-x201)1> nodes().
[]
```

1. Start erlang on a computer a2-asrock

   erl -sname b@a2-asrock
2. Establish link between nodes using computer a2-x201:

   (a@a2-x201)2> net_adm:ping('b@a2-asrock').
   pong
   (a@a2-x201)3> nodes().
   ['b@a2-asrock']
3. Everything looks ok at the moment.
4. Starting remote shell on a2-asrock from a2-x201

   CTRL+ G

   -->r 'b2@a2-asrock'
   -->j
   1  {shell,start,[init]}
   2* {'b2@a2-asrock',shell,start,[]}
   -->c

   *** ERROR: Shell process terminated! (^G to start new job) ***
5. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing remoting on 'b2@a2-asrock' instead of 'b@a2-rock' which is the name of the created node. You're pinging 'b@a2-asrock' but you're trying to connect to 'b2@a2-asrock' instead. Seems that you have a typo in there.

Comment: Thanks it is works! It looks like I do not fully understand difference between **NODE** and **job**. So I tried to start one more node remotely instead of new  job.

Comment: Also, you can use the -remsh flag to connect to the shell of a remote node: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html